# Как передать на сервер все checkbox, даже не отмеченные?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Как правильно реализовать запись checkbox в бд? Если я их выбираю то постом получаю данные только выбранных. А вот если я хочу снят галочку и, что бы в бд записалось, то что галочка снята. Подскажите.(Вариант ajax не подойдет) Наверно нужно как то получать данные со всех checkbox или используя JQuery по событию.(не очень хорошо JQuery и JS знаю, думаю это используя их делается)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<input name="check[]" value="<?php echo $d->id; ?>" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" <?php if($d->mark == 1):?>checked <?php endif;?>>
```

Answer (score -1):

Без js можно создать дубликат инпута, если чекбокс не выбран то придет значение спрятанного инпута:

```
<input name="check[]" value="0" type="hidden">
<input name="check[]" value="<?php echo $d->id; ?>" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" <?php if($d->mark == 1):?>checked <?php endif;?>>
```

Comment: немного не то.   Думаю человеку нужно понять как в базе записывать то что чекбокс отжат.

Comment: @webservice, думаю это как раз то, подозреваю запись в базе `bool` или `tinyint`, поэтому `0` там прекрасно подойдет.

Comment: Да, скорее всего) Но: 1) значение придёт всегда.
2) человеку нужно как-то обработать не выбранные инпуты

В вашем случае, имея 2 чекбокса мы получим что-то такое при активном состоянии
`Array ( [check] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 0 [3] => 2 ) )`
и что-то такое при их пассивном состоянии
`Array ( [check] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 ) )`
Что не решает проблему

Comment: Как вообще такое правильно сделать? добавив пустой инпут проблему не решает, наверно через js лучше отслеживать?

Comment: А если так сделать: Пришло значение одного  чекбокса в пост, а остальных нет. И тогда в запросы обновить все чекбоксы на 0 кроме того который пришел в посте.

Comment: @Andrii, если в одной записи все значения надо обновлять, то я так и делал бы. А если в разных, то тогда уже на js костылить

Comment: Как передать значение <> с несколькими значениями? `"UPDATE task_list SET mark = '$mark' WHERE id <> (".$checkboxId.")";` ;$mark = 0. а $checkboxId тут значения (5,7,8)

Comment: Я думаю логично, что если этот чекбокс не попал в $_POST, значит он не был отмечен.....
Иначе прям если необходимо что - бы в $_POST пришло имя это чекбокса и его признак "отмеченности", то здесь на js обход всех импутов на предмет `checked` и составление объекта FormData в ручную и отправка его аяксом, либо другим удобным способом.

Answer (score -1):

Если есть список значений в переменной, то реализуй перебор значений и проверку на есть оно в массиве что приходит или нет.

```
//$inputs - массив возможных значений наших чекбоксов
foreach($inputs as &$input){
    if(in_array($input,$_POST['check'])){
      //Если чекбокс выбран.
    }else{
      //Если нет
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Я бы это сделал так:

```js
(function(){
  var dataToBeSend = {};
  $.each($("[type='checkbox']"), function(i,item){
    dataToBeSend[$(item).data("name")] = $(item).prop('checked');
  });
  // какой-то модуль, который занимается ajax вызовами
  //_ajaxModule.call(url, dataToBeSend);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="canvas">
    <input type="checkbox" data-name="first">
    <input type="checkbox" data-name="second">
    <input type="checkbox" data-name="third">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```